# How can align the avatar image in the center, when use UserAccountsDrawerHeader in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, drawer

When i want to use UserAccountsDrawerHeader in flutter endDrawer, how can set all of the avatar image and accountEmail and accountName  align in **center** of drawer, in my code every thing align in left ?

**this is my code:**

```
endDrawer: Drawer(
            child: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                sigmaX: 1.8,
                sigmaY: 1.8,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
              Center( child:
              UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountEmail: Text(
                user.email ?? "user Email",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Theme
                        .of(context)
                        .colorScheme
                        .onPrimary),
              ),
              accountName: Text(
                user.fullName ?? user.username ?? "user Name",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Theme
                        .of(context)
                        .colorScheme
                        .onPrimary),
              ),
              currentAccountPicture: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Container(
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => ProfileScreen(
                              user: user,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
```

i use Center widget but it's not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mam_65](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5723285/mam-65) Try to wrap them in `Row`:

```
...    
child: UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
       accountEmail: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        user.email ?? "user Email",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
        accountName: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        user.fullName ?? user.username ?? "user Name",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
...
```

**NOTE:** No way to center the `currentAccountPicture` because is wrapped in a `Row` with `otherAccountsPictures` (max 3 widgets). To do this you've to customize a `Drawer` yourself.

Comment: Warp with Row is true for accountEmail and accountName but for currentAccountPicture not work did you have solution for that ?